# Awesomium javascript error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Tags: c#, javascript, awesomium

I am executing this javascript into Awesomium WebControl

```
                  function getImage(img) {
                        var canvas = document.createElement(\"canvas\");
                        canvas.width = img.width;
                        canvas.height = img.height;
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext(\"2d\");
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
                        try{
                              var imgData=ctx.getImageData(10,10,50,50);
                              alert(imgData);
                        }catch(err){" +
                              alert(err);" +
                        }
                  }
```

Now this code giving this alert :

> Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18

Now this is a fairly common code for javascript. Someone told me that If I can set the right flag then it can be turned off. So the code should be like this:

```
WebCore.Initialize(new WebConfig { AdditionalOptions = new[] { "--allow-file-access-from-files" } });
```

This "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag works for Chrome.
Now do anyone know anything about this. And suggestion or code sample will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using version [1.6.6](http://awesomium.com/downloads/awesomium_v1.6.6_sdk_win.exe). Use this code :

```
        WebCoreConfig config = new WebCoreConfig();
        config.DisableSameOriginPolicy = true;
        WebCore.Initialize(config, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these These settings have been moved to the **WebSessionProvider**:
http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/819/disablesameoriginpolicy.html

Note: **FileAccessFromFileURL** and **UniversalAccessFromFileURL**

Example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <controls:WebSessionProvider x:Key="mySession" DataPath=".\Cache">
       <core:WebPreferences 
            FileAccessFromFileURL="True"
            UniversalAccessFromFileURL="True"
            SmoothScrolling="True" 
            DefaultEncoding="iso-8859-7" />
     </controls:WebSessionProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<awe:WebControl Name="webControl"
                    WebSession="{Binding Source={StaticResource mySession}}" 
                    Source="file:///k:/something/index.html"
                    DocumentReady="webControl_DocumentReady"
                    ></awe:WebControl>
```